# How to remove duplicate contents?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, solr, sphinx

I've a classified website (in PHP and Mysql) where users can post their ads free of cost. But users often post duplicate ads. The script do not allow them to post exact duplicate contents, so they do this by changing one or two character.

Is there any way to find the duplicate ad and alert the user (even if they modified some portion of the text)?

My site is in PHP and Mysql. I'm using sphix for searching. Thinking of changing this to mongodb and apache solr.

Comment: How far do you want to go in checking wether the content is duplicate? How many characters? You could work with a restriction that people can only post an ad once a week or so.

Comment: Are your users adding fake parameters, i.e. http://foo.com/image.png?fakeparam=1? In this case, you could strip off all of the parameters and only consider the parameterless URL. However, this won't stop people from reuploading the same file with a different name...

Comment: @ Alexander Cogneau I'll consider the ad as duplicate if the content is 80% similar (except stop words like is, the, was, there, etc).. 

No, we can not restrict the people posting multiple ads in same day. We can manually find out the duplicate contents posted in same day, but can not search on one week old posts

Comment: You will need to check it is by the same user, multiple users posting 80% similar ad is not rare but is also commonly used for this purpose as well as legitimately

Answer (score 2):

Go and have a loot at

Calculate the similarity between two strings
http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

OR

Calculate Levenshtein distance between two strings
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which break the sentence into words and then match each words with the table and then find percentage of matching in database. Based on the percentage you can make the decision. For less database checking you can remove the common words and verbs, which you can store in a array. This is my personal opinion may be there are some other better techniques. But I must say it is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Levenstein distance, jarowinkler, plagiarism algorithms.. Look them them up on SO

I would start with simple levenstein distance

Comment: Looks like some manual quality control will be needed. For example two different users can post an ad for vacant apartments on the same street: `25 Lake Ave` and `26 Lake Ave` - if you use Levenshtein distance, then it may mark one as duplicate. However duplicate posts can be like `25 Lake Ave` and `25 Lake Avenue`, which has higher Levenshtein distance!